# hive 0.11 decimal precision error

Tags: hive

I am trying to create a hive table with decimal precision column. For some reason, I could able to create column of datatype decimal but not with precision.Eg: b decimal is OK, but for b decimal(3,3). I keep getting error

**mismatched input '(' excepting ) near 'decimal' in create table statement.**

Hive> create table testbd.test1_decimal (b decimal (3,3));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive 0.11 does not support precision and scale for decimal. [HIVE-3976](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3976) added support for decimal scale and precision, and is available in Hive 0.13.